# How use stringByEvaluatingJavaScript with params

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I'am trying to do this function in Swift 3

```
self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "setFacebookResult(\(self.dict),\(self.userToken))")
```

I have to pass the token and the result to a global function in javascript
but this params dont go correctly to the method. Pls help me!

Comment: Where you are calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` ?

Comment: right there, when i pass int values go correctly but strings go wrong

Comment: What you mean by **right there, when i pass int values go correctly but strings go wrong**, In your code you are passing Dictionary not string.

Comment: well, i call this function inside graphRequest.start if error == nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format it correctly for javascript.

Note that when using strings, you can't do something like:

```
let aString = "myTestString"
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "var myString = \(aString)")
```

instead you have to format it with `""`:

```
let aString = "myTestString"
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "var myString = \"\(aString)\"")
```

Comment: I can resolve the issue converting the result to JSON and use the JSON as param. Ty